# Reading data from stored data in arraylist

Tags: java, jdbc, arraylist

Can someone help me i have those classes, and i want read out the getAllCustomer(), but i have no idea how i can implent it in my main method.
I tried already several things, but it didn't work well. Can anyone help me? :P

```
public static ArrayList<Customer> getAllCustomer() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection conn=DBConnection.getDBConnection().getConnection();
    Statement stm;
    stm = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "Select * From Customer";
    ResultSet rst;
    rst = stm.executeQuery(sql);
    ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rst.next()) {
        Customer customer = new Customer(rst.getString("id"), rst.getString("name"), rst.getString("address"), rst.getDouble("salary"));
        customerList.add(customer);
    }
    return customerList;
}
```

this is my  model class

```
      public class Customer {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String salary;
    private String address;

    public Customer (String pId, String pName, String pSalary, String pAddress) {
        id = pId;
        name = pName;
        salary = pSalary;
        adress = pAddress;

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(String salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Customer` class apparently has no constructor, so what are you trying to call in `getAllCustomer()`?
Apart from that, what do you mean when you say "it didn't work well"? What are you trying to achieve? How did you try it? What obstacle did you encounter? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: DO NOT USE `select *`

Comment: Okay, i added the crunstructor... i have to meniton its not the real code, i found out that code on the internet. But there was no discription how to call the method.

Comment: @user902383 What should I write when i wanna find all data records?

Comment: I mean with it didn't work well i found no way that I can compile the code. (When i want to call method getAllCustomers();

Comment: "address" and "salary" are inverted between your constructor arguments and your Customer creation.
Also, you should be more precise concerning your question. Have you some errors ? What are they? ...

Comment: @Zycho Okay, changed that little mistake. I just want to know how I can show all the data records on the Screen with println. I found no way for it.

Comment: @CallMeBronxy `select [column names]` `select *` is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your getAllCustomer() method is in class A . then in your main method, you do as follows

```
public void main(String[] args){
 List<Customer> customers =  A.getAllCustomer();
}
```

Based on the nature of your question, [this JDBC tutorial will help you](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jdbc-tutorials/)

Comment: But I first need an instance of the Class A?

Comment: as long as you have a class A, then you can all A.getAllCustomer(), without an instance of A, because  getAllCustomer() is static (class level method)

Comment: Okay, i told before that this is just a example, on my real code i missed the static, now it seems to work fine. :)  Thaanks^^

Comment: Glad that it worked, so you can  accept this answer now

Answer (score 0):

The data type of your Salary field is String but you are getting the value as double.

All you need to do is to change the rst.getDouble("salary") to rst.getString("salary")

To call the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)

  ArrayList<Customer> customers = YourDALClass.getAllCustomer();
  for(Customer c : customers){
     System.out.println(c.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. works now ! the mistake with the getDouble was only in example, on my real code i only used getStrings ;)